# How to create dynamic navigation based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When visitor Select a destination, (e.g., Mars) and click on button they go to the relevant page.

Is there a better way to do it?

Example:

Label for button:

```
<label class="destinationlabel">
<input type="radio" class="field-radio" name="destiny" value="Mars">
<span class="MarsSpanClass" title="Mars">Mars</span>
</label>

<label class="destinationlabel">
<input type="radio" class="field-radio" name="moon" value="Moon">
<span class="MoonSpanClass" title="Mars">Moon</span>
</label>
```

Button DIV:

```
 <div class="box">
  <button id="gobutton" class="buttonclass">
    <i class="buttontextclass"></i>
    Go
  </button>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You could just have links to those pages

Comment: An example please? <a> doesn't work. I will need a script? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a working example of it going to the relevant page? Based on this sample there would need to be a script in place to cause the navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each radio button could store the location it corresponds to in the `value` attribute. Then, when the button gets clicked, it reads the selected radio button's `value` attribute and changes the `window.location` to that URL.

Your HTML can be simplified because the `label` element can do the job that you are currently using the `span` elements for.

```js
document.getElementById("gobutton").addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Get the value of the checked radio button
  var newLocation = document.querySelector("input[name='destiny']:checked").value;
  alert("Redirecting to: " + newLocation);  // Just for testing
  window.location = newLocation;            // Redirect to the new location
});;
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="field-radio" name="destiny" id="mars" value="mars.html">
<label for="mars" class="destinylabel">Mars</label>

<input type="radio" class="field-radio" name="destiny" id="moon" value="moon.html">
<label for="moon" class="destinylabel">Moon</label>


 <div class="box">
  <button id="gobutton" class="buttonclass">
    <i class="buttontextclass"></i>
    Go
  </button>
</div>
```